# Exclude first child with XSL-T

Tags: xslt, xpath, css-selectors

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple, but I can't find the way to. I just want to iterate over the children of a node excluding the first child.

For instance, in this XML snippet, I would want all the `<bar>` elements, except the first one:

```
<foo>
    <Bar>Example</Bar>
    <Bar>This is an example</Bar>
    <Bar>Another example</Bar>
    <Bar>Bar</Bar>
</foo>
```

There is no common attribute by which I can filter (like an `id` tag or something similar).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can always use `position` together with `xsl:when`.

```
<xsl:when test="node[position() > 1]">
  <!-- Do my stuff -->
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: ... and I feel like a n00b. `<for-each select="foo/Bar[position() > 1]">` Thank you.

Comment: @zneak - we were all there... too many things to keep in our brain in the same time.

Comment: `node.position() != 1` is not a syntactically-correct XPath expression.

Comment: The answer still contains a syntactically incorrect XPath expression! Why don't you try to run the code and to post only correct code?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - I was giving an example, not copy/paste code.

Comment: Examples need to be correct in order to be useful. I never reply with untested code.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: to be honest and as my first comment can testimony, he was the first to answer and I understood what he meant right away. For the rest of the world, yeah, working code is useful, but my requirements weren't even that high.

Comment: @zneak: that's good, but this code is seen by anybody and people will just copy it and try to use it and only then will understand it is not even syntactically correct. This is why I have the principle never to post untested code.

Answer (score 4):

```
/foo/Bar[position() > 1]
```

For example, in C#:

```
[Test]
public void PositionBasedXPathExample()
{
    string xml = @"<foo>
                     <Bar>A</Bar>
                     <Bar>B</Bar>
                     <Bar>C</Bar>
                   </foo>";

    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var bars = xDocument.XPathSelectElements("/foo/Bar[position() > 1]")
        .Select(element => element.Value);

    Assert.That(bars, Is.EquivalentTo(new[] { "B", "C" }));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**`/foo/bar[position() > 1]`**

selects all `bar` elements with the exception of the first, that are children of the top element, which is `foo`.

**`(//bar)[position() >1]`**

selects all `bar` elements in in any XML document, with the exception of the first `bar` element in this document.

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="foo/Bar[position() > 1]" />
```

or the same xpath for `for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="foo/Bar[position() > 1]">
    …
</xsl:for-each>
```