# Getting the node name of an unknown XML node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an XML stylesheet with variable child nodes, something like this:

```
<fooz>
 <foo>
  <bar id="11">
 </foo>
 <foo>
  <baz id="22">
 </foo>
 <foo>
  <biz id="33">
 </foo>
</fooz>
```

So I know I can get the id's without any problems using

```
<xsl:value-of select="foo/*/@id"/>
```

But I'm kind of lost when it comes to getting the node name like "bar", "baz" or "biz". I tried stuff like this without any happy results:

```
<xsl:value-of select="foo/node()"/>
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried the first xsl-statement with your xml-example, but I couldn't retrieve all the id-attributes with it, only the first.
To get all at once, I needed to use a for-each statement.

To get back the name of a node, you can use :

```
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
```

To get all names under the foo elements, I've come up with the following :

```
<xsl:for-each select="/fooz/foo/*">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing... making a for-each loop.

Comment: Actually, how do you not include one node? Like show all but the local-name of biz?

Comment: If you know that you want to exclude all element named "biz', I would use an if statement.
For a fixed position, you could use the function "position()"
See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574944/exclude-first-child-with-xsl-t